# Forced redeployment of Lambda function from S3?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function defined in a Cloudformation template with a reference to an S3 bucket and key where I have saved a zipfile containing the Lambda source in the usual fashion. I have a separate CI build process building the Lambda function and dumping it into S3. Now I want the S3 key within the Cloudformation template to be static, I don't want to be changing it for every Lambda commit+rebuild. But Cloudformation thinks the Lambda hasn't changed because the S3 key hasn't changed, even though the contents of the zipfile have been changed.

Must I change the S3 key each time to trigger Lambda redeployment, or is there a way to force Lambda redeployment via Cloudformation whilst retaining the static key ?

Comment: I used aws sdk for updating the lambda code. Is it possible for you to do this through sdk?

Comment: no, need to use CF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, CFT doesn't realise the changes since the S3 key remains same despite the content of it is changed.

As you mentioned, can have the S3 Key different from the previous CFT execution so that the lambda code gets deployed.

You will have to keep the S3 key as CFT parameter

Otherwise, try using SAM Packaging in AWS Code Build and use Code Deploy with Cloud Formation.

Here, the location will not be mentioned as zip, instead takes the code path and builds it and template gets updated with the new deployment package location everytime. (See buildspec.yml in CodeBuild)

**References:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/build-pipeline.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-deploying.html

Hope this helps.